# ASP.Classic Getting value from input to POST parameter

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

**Please excuse me if this question is dumb.**

I need to get an input value and pass it in a POST parameter like follow:

```
SQL = "[proc_Happy]" & Request.Cookies("UserID")& "," & Request.Form("MYINPUTFIELD")
```

I have tried hardcoding MYINPUTFIELD with (it worked!):

```
  SQL = "[proc_Happy]" & Request.Cookies("UserID")& "," & 54555152
```

My input in the asp page looks as follow:

```
<input type="number" name="MYINPUTFIELD " id="MYINPUTFIELD" value="<%=MYINPUTFIELD%>">
```

**Things I  have tried:**

Getting the value with JS - failed.

**Notes:**
MYINPUTFIELD is an int

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection . Your code is very vulnerable as is.

Comment: What errors do you get? What specifically does not work? What do you get if you write your string back to the page? Are you sure you have set the method of the form to POST **not** GET

Comment: Thank you @mjwills for the notes, this project is a test, not a production one - thanks!

Comment: Hi @JonP, there is no error, the value from the asp page is not being read.

Comment: `this project is a test, not a production one` Test or otherwise, you shouldn't use that code. Doing it properly takes no extra time, and encourages good practices that will help you in future.

Comment: Is the field set to `disabled` at any point by javascript? Are there any redirects happening? The code you have provided should work *if the form is set to POST not GET* . Check the length of `Request.Form` to see if anything is being passed back in the Form object/

Comment: I'm with @jon-p here. It looks like `<form action='post'>` is missing. @Yosh, check with `Request.QueryString("MYINPUTFIELD")` if the value is present there. I also recognize a trailing space in `name="MYINPUTFIELD "` in your code sample.

Comment: Since he is using stored procedure, parameters are validated.  MYINPUTFIELD must be an int.  So, code is not really vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Is your input field in a form, i.e. is it between `<form...>` and `</form>` tags? If no, that's your problem right there. If yes, what does the `<form...>` tag have in it? Does it say `method='get'`? If yes, then your inputs are being put in the querystring, not the form object. For `Request.Form(...)` to work, your form needs to say `method='post'`.

If you need this code to work with both form methods, you can do something like

```
dim MyInputField
MyInputField = Request.Querystring("MyInputField")
If MyInputField = "" Then MyInputField = Request.Form("MyInputField")
'make the "OMGSQLINJECTION!!1!" people just go away already
'(note to such people: he's using a frigging stored procedure.)
If Not Isnumeric(MyInputField) Then 
    MyInputField = 0 
End If
SQL = "[proc_Happy]" & Request.Cookies("UserID")& "," & MyInputField
```